# How to add an ID attribute to a table tr through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, attributes

I have a table that is constructed using the WordPress Settings API. The table is outputted like this:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="feedblitz_rss_link">FeedBlitz RSS URL:</label></th>
    <td><input class="regular-text" type="text" id="feedblitz_rss_link" name="aswfe_options[feedblitz_rss_link]" value="" />
    <br />
    <span class="description">Enter the URL to your Feedblitz RSS Feed.</span></td>
</tr>
```

In each table row there is a form field that contains an ID. I would like to take that ID and assign it to the `<tr>` of the row, so that the row would look like this:

```
<tr id="feedblitz_rss_link">
    <th scope="row"><label for="feedblitz_rss_link">FeedBlitz RSS URL:</label></th>
    <td><input class="regular-text" type="text" id="feedblitz_rss_link" name="aswfe_options[feedblitz_rss_link]" value="" />
    <br />
    <span class="description">Enter the URL to your Feedblitz RSS Feed.</span></td>
</tr>
```

I want to do this so that then I can get at each table row through jQuery and hide or display each row that is needed.

**== Update ==**

I have the table now assigning dat-rel attributes to each table row thanks to @Mike & @Dennis using this code:

```
$(".aswfe-admin .form-table tr input").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");        
    $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-rel", id);
});
```

Now I seem to be having issues getting at each row and hiding them. I thought I could use something like this but this code hides the whole table, whereas I only want to hide the specific row with the specific `data-rel` attribute.

```
$(".form-table tr").data("rel", "feedblitz_rss_link").hide();
```

Comment: I would Matt, however I don't know how to get at the text field input ID through jQuery and assign it to each table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("tr input").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");        
    $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-feed-id", id);
});
```

Note that this answer is tailored to the markup provided and assumes it won't conflict with other tables on your page.

You can access access the rows and inspect them later via

```
$("[data-feed-id]").each(function() {
     ...do stuff....
});
```

Starting to sound like the rows you're looking to hide are well known. You can accomplish this easily enough with (given the same markup above)

```
$("#some_known_id").parent().parent().hide();
```

See fiddle @
http://jsfiddle.net/NWU5Q/

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Mike, was exactly what I was after. Just wasn't sure how to get at the input fields within the table rows.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Would you recommend adding another attribute to the table row instead of the ID?

Comment: @Jason - Dennis has a good point. You could opt for a data attribute instead. I'll update w/ an example.

Comment: Thank again Mike. Could I just use like the "data-rel" attribute or another HTML element to add to the table row?

Comment: The input elements already have ids.  Just get them and call parent() twice on them to get the row - you don't need to fiddle with tr attributes.

Comment: I thought this would be the best approach as further down in the code I might need to hide the table row that has the ID of <tr data-rel="feedblitz_rss_link"> for example. Not totally sure though. Still modifying the code to get it to hide the table rows. I changed the row "ID" attribute to "data-rel".

Comment: @Jason - are you hard coding some of these IDs into the code later on?  In your question update, you have code specifically targeting feedblitz_rss_link. Do you just have a constant list of these IDs that you want to hide? If so, then Dennis was right, you have no need to add an attribute.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you again. Yes I am hard coding the ID later on so that I can hide or display each row. Just one last question. I understand how to get at an ID to hide it in jQuery. $('#feedblitz_rss_link').hide(); however if I am using the "data-rel" attribute instead of the ID, how would I get at that?

Comment: @Jason - then you should be able to get away with the parent().parent().hide() and parent().parent().show() methods.

Comment: Got it!. Yes your added code worked great. $("#feedblitz_rss_link").parent().parent().hide(); It was only supposed to be a 5 minute job this morning, however turned into hours. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your `tr` on many ways:

```
$('table tr:nth(0)').slideToggle();
$('table tr td').find('#feedblitz_rss_link').parent().slideToggle();
$('table tr td label').indexOf ("RSS URL") > -1
...
```

**update:** or you can use [wordpress hooks](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really need to assign the ID to each table row as each row will have a unique ID. I need to hide the whole row and not just the table th or table td. I would like to do it on the fly if possible as there are up to 50 table rows, and I need to get at about 5 of them.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ysSva/)**

You are hiding the row with invalid syntax.
From beginning, I think that you have multiple `tr`, so working with ID
isn't a good idea. Let get the `input` by the `class` and its hierarchy:

```
$('tr > th + td > .regular-text').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id', id);
});
```

Now you want to show/hide the `tr` element (for example by clicking on it):

```
$('tr[data-id]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```